# How to implement button function in fragments in Android studio

Tags: android

**FeedFragment.java**

```java
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {

    Button bt_scan;
    private Object Button;

    public FeedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

        bt_scan = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bt_scan);
        bt_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent MainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivityQR.class);
                startActivity(MainIntent);
           /* if you want to finish the first activity then just call
            finish(); */
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

I already tried but the camera for scanning QR Code wont come out

Comment: whats the problem? you aren't getting click event ?

Comment: Have you added Camera permissions logic?

Comment: @Blackmamba i can click. but the camera wont come out

Comment: @Code0987 i have added it. but still the same

Comment: why are you calling this Intent MainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivityQR.class);
            startActivity(MainIntent); if you want to open camera @MuhamadQiwamuddin

Comment: @MuhamadQiwamuddin Provide us more code, where you are opening the camera, where you are asking permissions ...

Comment: @Blackmamba your suggestion?

Comment: @Blackmamba it go only for xml files

Answer (score 0):

The use of the camera require a permission request and a declaration in the AndroidManifest file

Comment: i have done that. because i use extends fragment the camera wont come out